# Java - using replaceAll without getting a space

Tags: java, string

I have a problem using replace all, it add a space instead of the replaced words. A simple example:

```
String str= "I like java"; 
str.replaceAll("java","");
```

gives "I like(a space here)"

```
String str= "I like java"; 
str.replaceAll("like","");
```

gives "I(2 spaces here)java"

```
String str= "I like java"; 
str.replaceAll("I","");
```

gives "(2 spaces here)like java"

How can I truncate this space just by using replaceAll ?  Iguess it has something to do with the replacing argument(""), right ?

Note: I have a few words that should be deleted if found in a string, and I don't know where they'll be found.

Thanks

Comment: Well, since `" java"` and `" like"` are too obvious, we better wait for a more special way to do that :D. Btw you should use `replace`, not `replaceAll`.

Comment: you are aking to replace word, not space+word, It is working as expected

Comment: @Tom There's no way to get rid of the additional space ?

Comment: Sure there are and I already showed one.

Comment: @Tom it solves that particular problem, but what if I need to replace "I" at the begging ? remember - I don't know where the replaced words will be found. I need a general solution. Any idea ?

Comment: You then just need to search for two things: "how to remove spaces at the start and the end of Strings" and "how to replace two spaces with one". There are existing SO Q/A for both of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing "java" with "", leaving the two spaces you originally had in your string, rather than replacing " java" (note the space).  But, this would work...

```
String str= "I like java"; 
str = str.replaceAll(" java","");
```

If you're looking to replace only one of the spaces around that word, with a preference for the first space, you might do this...

```
String regex = " like|like ";
System.out.println("I like java".replaceAll(regex,""));
System.out.println("like java".replaceAll(regex,""));
```

Comment: It solves that particular problem, but  if I want to replace "I" at the begging ? remember - I don't know where the replaced words will be found. I need a general solution. Any idea ?

Comment: I answered your question, as you did not provide those specifics until now.  You'd have to be more specific than wanting a "general solution".

Comment: Right, I know, that's why I corrected that. Any idea ?

Comment: Not really, because I don't know what you mean by generic solution.  replaceAll() takes a regular expression, so the sky is the limit. 

If you're looking to replace only one of the spaces around that word, with a preference for the first space, you might do this...

    String regex = " like|like ";
    System.out.println("I like java".replaceAll(regex,""));
    System.out.println("like java".replaceAll(regex,""));